# JavaScript error with paging in community discussion SP 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, view, discussion-board, community-site

I have a community site with many discusssions. One of them is a discussion divided into 3 pages (each answer has text and animated gif). When I try to go to page 2, in default (Flat) view mode, I have a JavaScript error. This doesn't append in other view modes. Can anyone help me?

## Error displayed

### Chrome

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'RefreshCurrent' of undefined

Details in console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> (anonymous function) init.js?rev=ZCyl%2Bj%2B4NZLoeodWTEXQ0Q%3D%3D:1
>
> EnsureScript init.js?rev=ZCyl%2Bj%2B4NZLoeodWTEXQ0Q%3D%3D:1
>
> EnsureScriptFunc    sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> SP.UI.Discussions.ReplyBoxControl.show    sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> SP.UI.Discussions.ReplyBoxControl.transferState    sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> SP.UI.Discussions.ForumViewState.$22_0    sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> (anonymous function)    sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> SP.UI.Discussions.ForumViewState.DeferredAnimatedRefreshHandler.$1F_0    sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D:2
>
> SP.UI.Discussions.ForumViewState.DeferredAnimatedRefreshHandler.onAnimationCompleteHandler    ScriptResource.axd?d=hcWaKNwWA2WhwXswNF7O-FBRMblD1hhHuIFX_8zVTjKZe38dLtG-gh-i_nRAAXANzooOn9YaiB0cvo…:5
>
> (anonymous function)    core.js?rev=%2FmcwmyWAFSbQRHlXU4BIBg%3D%3D:1
>
> AnimationUnit.StepAnimation    core.js?rev=%2FmcwmyWAFSbQRHlXU4BIBg%3D%3D:1
>
> AnimationEngine.StepAllAnimations    core.js?rev=%2FmcwmyWAFSbQRHlXU4BIBg%3D%3D:1
>
> AnimationEngine.LocalStepper

### Firefox

> TypeError: a is undefined

Details from console:

> TypeError: c is null    sp.ui.discussions.js:2

### IE8

> Type error. 'Undefined' a la valeur Null ou n'est pas un objet

Details from console:

> Objet requis  sp.ui.discussions.js?rev=Ctp9%2FvLjNfusJYnhCPlrrg%3D%3D, Ligne 2 Caractère 60983

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: This behavior appends in a custom category only, no problems with General items

Comment: I have the same problem. I have seen that this occurs when you mark a comment as "best answer" and the answer is not on the first page. Did you find the solution? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't remember it: it was a long time ago! :(